# How to access classes and methods of vb.net native dll file from jna or other library

Tags: java, dll, java-native-interface, native, jna

**What I have**
a) I have used jna library.
b) My dll is vb.net native dll file.
c) You can check this link for more about dll [link](http://www.hybrid-solutions.com/support/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/2062)

**My source code is following**

Interface

```
package com.dll.lib;

import com.sun.jna.Library;
import com.sun.jna.Native;

public interface BrowseControl extends Library {
    BrowseControl instance = (BrowseControl)Native.loadLibrary("Vertex FXBOAPI10.5.9", BrowseControl.class);
}
```

Class

```
package com.dll.main;

import com.dll.lib.BrowseControl;

public class MainTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BrowseControl control=BrowseControl.instance;
            System.out.println("Brwoser: "+control.getClass());
        }  
    }

}
```

This code is working.

**What I want**
a) how to access their classes and method from dll in java programming language?

b) how to reference the `{VertexFX Backoffice API}` Dll, then define Object of type `CVertexFXBOAPI` class, after that call the methods `Object.SetLoginInfo` and `Object.Login`

Thanks

Comment: Please edit your answer. The code for your class is not included, you have not included the link properly. Your question is hard to understand, I'm not sure exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Yep_It's_Me
You can now check the question

Comment: I don't think JNA can do .NET or COM. Also, not sure why you call the DLL "native."

Comment: You're going to have to go Java -> C (via JNA or JNI - I'd prefer JNI) -> .NET.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5991705/how-to-call-vb-net-dll-from-c-call-the-functions-also-not-dll-file-only for starters on how to get from C -> .NET

Comment: You can do JNI with C++/CLI. If you want to stick with JNA, you could export Visual Basic module methods as [DLL function exports](https://sites.google.com/site/robertgiesecke/Home/uploads/unmanagedexports), which would make sense to term "native." Of course, that doesn't easily get you to your goal of accessing classes. Alternatively, there are products for Java-.NET and Java-COM bridging out there. (I mention COM because many .NET assemblies and classes opt-in to .NET's COM-Callable Wrapper feature.)

Comment: Just create a middleware c program to be the interface between java and .net then use jna, I tried before but I think is not possible (or suitable)  do that directly

Answer (score 0):

Yo can use native code from shared library via JNI. JNI provides bridge between Java and your code. However, you have to make sure that you keep naming convention for your native routines.

In your case (where you have DLL with native code you want to call) you can go via JNI wrapper that will code the code. This way, you can leave DLL as it is.

Take a look here for a sample code where:

http://jnicookbook.owsiak.org/recipe-No-018/

This is not exactly what you are looking for (as the code is for macOS/Linux) but the schema will be very similar.

Your JNI wrapper (called from Java) - this will be a native code - will load library you already have (one that is inside DLL produced by somebody else). Then, you will need to call a function from that DLL.